# How do I show the simulation button in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been working on my first iOS app.  Recently we released the first version on the app store.  I'm not sure if it's related but since releasing the first version I have noticed that the button to start a simulation is now gone.  In it's place in the top left is an option that says "app_name" > My Mac.  This doesn't make sense because this is an iOS app and the simulator has always worked before.  Does anyone know what might be going on?

[This is how it was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSbgj.png)

[This is how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0WGC.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question kindly explain more

Comment: Added links to screenshots that hopefully clear up the question

Comment: you have selected the work target click on targets and select your app target if you do not know how to do it let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Evidence Charts` your app? If not, click on it to expand the list and select your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and you need to expand xcode's window to a really big size (outwards not downwards) hope this helps. This shouldn't be a bug with your app just a bug with xcode.

update :  you should also try what Stephenye said

Comment: This answer does not make sense

Comment: I meant if the run button or the simulation button had disappeared completely, then you would need to resize the xcode window until the button came back (worked for me)